# Logits and Labels must have the same shape : Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, shapes, valueerror

I m trying to classify Cats vs Dogs Using a CNN Network, However despite checking twice I am not able to find the error where it is coming . According to me the loss functions and shapes are in order , still I am not able to find the source of the error

```
!unzip cats_and_dogs.zip
PATH = 'cats_and_dogs'
train_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'train')
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 directory=train_dir,
                                                 target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                 class_mode='binary')
augmented_images = [train_data_gen[0][0][0] for i in range(5)]
plotImages(augmented_images)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(25,kernel_size=3,input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3),activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(25,kernel_size=3,activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(25,kernel_size=3,activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())
model.add(Conv2D(25,kernel_size=3,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(64,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam",metrics=['accuracy'],loss='binary_crossentropy')
history = model.fit_generator(train_data_gen)
```

The error that I'm struggling with is

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 15, 15, 1) vs (None, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to Flatten my Tensor before flowing it to Dense layers

Comment: I think you should mark this answer as accepted if it solved your problem